# Is there a word for a member of a roster?

Tags: single-word-requests

If a roster is a list of people, is there a word for a single member of the roster?

As in, "We're always growing our roster! Apply today and you could be accepted to be a ______ tomorrow!"

What would that word be?

Comment: Does 'member' not work? What is the roster for? For example, if it is for a team, the member could be 'teammate'.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. What has your research turned up? (I think that *member* would be a fine word.)

Comment: ... Rosterfarian?

Comment: The roster is for a media network, 'member' does work, but I was wondering if there was a word that shared the etymology of 'roster' like 'rostee' (or 'rosterfarian', thanks for that @EdwinAshworth).

Comment: You're unlikely to find a generic term for "one in a roster." The etymology of *roster* is Dutch *rooster*, a table or list, derived from a gridiron or a grill. In English, *rosters* were first employed in military service to keep track of each individual's duties, and only in the 19th century gained its generic sense of a list individuals are enrolled into. No term specific to rosters has formed. The closest I can get is *enrollee* and *enlistee*, but those are more restricted to academics and military service, respectively.

Comment: But what are the individuals on your roster? Is it media companies? You haven't given us enough information to know why 'member' doesn't work, then how can we know when given something if it -does- work?

Comment: *"We're always growing our roster! Apply today and you could be accepted to be a ______ tomorrow!"* This is not idiomatic and there probably is no word. -- It would be *"Our roster is always growing! Apply today and you could be **on the roster** tomorrow!"*

Comment: Please realise that my suggestion was not meant to be taken seriously. Avoid.

Comment: I got it, I should have said "thanks for the laugh @EdwinAshworth"

Comment: "Apply today and you could be accepted tomorrow!" is a standard advertising promise. It should be obvious what you'll be accepted on.